# Networking service not responding

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ethernet

Networking is going down on some of our machines. This is happening very randomly. Restarting networking is fixing the issue. I found the following in the kernel logs:

```
Mar 19 18:19:05 <host> kernel: [4854950.244533] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
Mar 19 18:19:05 <host> kernel: [4854950.465902] ixgbe: eth1 NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: None
Mar 19 18:19:05 <host> kernel: [4854950.466895] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
Mar 19 18:19:16 <host> kernel: [4854960.725876] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
```

We have 10g card installed on these servers. (Intel Corporation 82599EB 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+).

OS: Debian 6.0
Kernel: 2.6.32-5-amd64
ixgbe version: 3.18.7

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible error sources:

- Peer (Other Server or Switch)
- Cable
- Yout NIC / Server

To find the cause, I would:

- monitor your interface with `mii-tool -l eth1`
- at the same time the peer (swich or other server)

If only one of them reports the link flapping, then it is likely that the the machine/ switch on which the flapping is reported is defect.

If both report the link flapping:

- Replace the cable
- Replace either server/ switch

...and see when the issue is gone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

mii-tool seems to be deprecated on the server.

But one strange thing happened. When I tried doing ethtool -t eth1, the same issue is reoccurring. So I think we can rule out the problem with Peer or cable

Comment: Yea I know but most distros ship mii-tool so I though I use this :)
So you see the problem on both sides?

Comment: The other side is a switch.

Comment: The strange thing which I noticed is the default route is getting disappeared when the issue is happening.

Comment: Well that's normal if the network is managed by tools like NetworkManager. They tend to automagically tear up and down things on link-up and link-down events.